# Register and load DLL in 64 bit

Tags: ruby, win32ole

I have two variants of DLLs 32 bit and 64 bit .. I registered them using `regsrv` and load them using `win32ole` API and register the methods ..

Now this works for me if I am registering a 32 bit DLL with a 32 bit Ruby process and 64bit DLL with a 64 bit ruby process

But my end goal is to use one variant 32 or 64 and register the DLL and get the result ..

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to do. You can't load a 32bit DLL into a 64bit process (or vice-versa).

Comment: Mat, I tried to fork out a process and used 64 bit ruby to launch my app which registered the dll using regsrv32 from the system32 folder and then load the dll using Win32OLE. I will again try this tomorrow and revert back